# Front-End user registration dynamic usernames - duplicate check

Tags: craft3, users, modules, registration, frontend-form

I have a front-end user registration form that generates a username automatically based on the first and last name inputs. This works as intended but on the off chance that two people have the same name, a check needs to be run on submit to see if the username already exists in the system. I'm currently utilizing `{{ actionInput('users/save-user') }}` to handle the form submit. I'm looking for a way to run a check before the action `users/save-user` returns the defualt duplicate username error. I've created a module to listen for the save event but it doesn't appear to be firing as intended. Within the module's `init()` function I'm running:

```
Event::on(
 User::class,
 User::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE,
 function (ModelEvent $event) {

  $loginName = $this->request->getRequiredBodyParam('username');
   
  if($user = Craft::$app->getUsers()->getUserByUsernameOrEmail($loginName)){

   // Change the username to username-(duplicateCount+1)
   // Create New User 

  } // else {

   // Create New User 

  // }
  }
);
```

using `use craft\elements\User;`

Disclaimer: I'm a novice when it comes to modules/plugins/controllers so any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The code looks ok at first glance – how are you checking if it's being executed? Try sticking a `\Craft::dd($loginName)` to see if the hook is actually firing. In this case it might just be down to a simple logic error.

Comment: To troubleshoot, I've been using ```die();``` within the event. The event fires correctly when a new user is created but fails to fire when loginName is a duplicate. Craft's default duplicate check appears to prevent ```EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE``` from firing.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. If there are validation errors, Craft won't try to save the user, so the hook won't fire. Try using `EVENT_BEFORE_VALIDATE` instead!

Comment: Somehow managed to miss that in the documentation, that worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working using:

`use yii\base\ModelEvent;`

`use craft\elements\User;`

```
Event::on(
User::class,
User::EVENT_BEFORE_VALIDATE,
function (ModelEvent $event) {

    // username format: john-doe
    $senderUsername = $this->request->getRequiredBodyParam('username');
    $senderEmail = $this->request->getRequiredBodyParam('email');
    $count = 1;

    if (!Craft::$app->getUsers()->getUserByUsernameOrEmail($senderEmail)){
        
        while(Craft::$app->getUsers()->getUserByUsernameOrEmail($senderUsername)){

            $name = explode("-", $senderUsername);
            $senderUsername = $name[0] . '-' . $name[1] . '-' . $count++;

        }
        
        $event->sender->username = $senderUsername;
    }
});
```